# JQuery make pressed button active and all other buttons inactive

Tags: jquery

I can make a single button stay active after moving off the button using the code below:

```
    $('.btn').click(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass('active')){
            $(this).removeClass('active')
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('active')
        }
    });
```

But I also want to make all other buttons on the page inactive. I tried the following but the expression to make all inactive needs to be outside the click function. How can I run a loop to iterate overall buttons when inside the click function?

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
    //make all inactive-doesn't work
    $( '.btn' ).each(function( ) {
        if($(this).hasClass('active')){
            $(this).removeClass('active')
        }
    });

    if($(this).hasClass('active')){
        $(this).removeClass('active')
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('active')
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to iterate using .each() - simply remove the .active class on the button click and apply it to the button that was clicked.

Just edited the post to also apply the inactive class to the buttons as well so clicking one button applies the inactive class to the buttons that weren't clicked.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.btn').click(function(){
    $('.btn').removeClass('active').addClass('inactive');
     $(this).removeClass('inactive').addClass('active');
    });
})
```

```css
.btn{color:white}
.active{background:green}
.inactive{background:red}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn inactive">test 1</button>
<button type="button" class="btn inactive">test 2</button>
<button type="button" class="btn inactive">test 3</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using not (this) : [Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shree/cjk9v899/1/)

```
 $('.btn').click(function() {
      if ($(this).is("active"))
        $('.btn').not(this).removeClass('active');
      else
        $(this).addClass('active');
      $('.btn').not(this).removeClass('active');
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, this works well but the answer from gavgrif is a bit shorter and simpler so I chose that as the answer

Answer (score 0):

As I understand problem is that you remove every single button class active and then you check if button has that class. That makes no sense because you have already removed it before, you can save it as variable true or false before you remove it for all buttons like this:

```
$(function(){
$('.btn').click(function(){
    var active = $(this).hasClass('active');
    //make all inactive-doesn't work
    $( '.btn' ).each(function( ) {
        if($(this).hasClass('active')){
            $(this).removeClass('active')
        }
    });

    if(active){
        $(this).removeClass('active')
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('active')
    }
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
    // remove all the active class
    $( '.btn').each(function() {
        $(this).removeClass('active')
    });
    //then the click button add class active 
    if($(this).hasClass('active')){
        $(this).removeClass('active')
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('active')
    }
```

});

Answer (score 0):

i make pressed button active and all other buttons are inactive in easy way only CSS and JavaScript
hope me this is simply way to lines of code and make happy
first u have must the proper links and CSS and javascript

```css
.btn-active {
    font-weight: bold !important;
    border-right: 5px solid blue !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="box 1"></div>
<div id="box 2"></div>
<div id="box 3"></div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#box 1").click(function(){
        $("#box 1").addClass('btn-active');
        $("#box 2").removeClass('btn-active');
        $("#box 3").removeClass('btn-active');
    });

    $("#box 2").click(function(){
        $("#box 2").addClass('btn-active');
        $("#box 1").removeClass('btn-active');
        $("#box 3").removeClass('btn-active');
    });

    $("#box 3").click(function(){
        $("#box 3").addClass('btn-active');
        $("#box 2").removeClass('btn-active');
        $("#box 1").removeClass('btn-active');
    });
});
```